# On Consistency of an Existence

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, infinite-combinatorics, independence-results

Let $\omega \leq \kappa <2^{\omega}$ , $\omega \leq\lambda \leq  \kappa$ and $D(\kappa, \lambda)$ be the statement:

For all $ \mathfrak{B} \subseteq \mathbf{P}(\omega)$ with $|\mathfrak{B}|=\kappa$ that is an almost disjoint family, there exists an $\mathfrak{A}\subseteq\mathfrak{B}$ with $|\mathfrak{A}|=\lambda$, such that for some $d\subseteq \omega $ we have:

1) $\forall x \in \mathfrak{A} ~~~~~~~~~~ |x\cap d |< \omega$

2) $\forall x \in \mathfrak{B} \smallsetminus\mathfrak{A} ~~ |x \smallsetminus d|< \omega$.

Now I have three questions:

**Question 1)** Does $MA(\kappa) \longrightarrow D(\kappa, \lambda) ?$

Or even:

**Question 2)** Is it true that $$Con(ZFC+ \neg CH+MA(\kappa)) \longrightarrow Con(ZFC+ D(\kappa , \lambda)) ?$$

**Remarks:** Clearly $ZFC \vdash D(\omega, \omega)$ and also $MA(\kappa) \longrightarrow D(\kappa, \omega) \wedge D(\kappa, \kappa).$
On the other hand what happens in the case $\lambda=\kappa$, when we add the condition $|\mathfrak{B} \smallsetminus \mathfrak{A}|=\kappa$ into the defination of $D(\kappa, \kappa)$? I mean, let $D^{+}(\kappa, \kappa)$ be $D(\kappa, \kappa)$ with this additional condition.

**Question 3)** Does $MA(\kappa) \longrightarrow D^{+}(\kappa, \kappa) ?$

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the quantifier or bounds on $\lambda$? Obviously it is false when $\lambda>\kappa$.

Comment: @ professor Joel David Hamkins thank you for remind the missed condition, I edited the question let \lambda be less than or equal to \kappa. Any additional condition such as regularity of \lambda is also pleasant or just for specific \lambda or \kappa such as if \lambda^{+} = \kappa.

Answer (score 4):

There is a counterexample to $D^+(\omega_1, \omega_1)$ in ZFC, so the answer to question 3 is no in general.  A $d$ satisfying your conditions (1) and (2) is said to *separate* $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B} \setminus \mathfrak{A}$. Luzin showed there is an almost disjoint family $\mathfrak{B}$ of size $\aleph_1$ such that for any two uncountable disjoint subfamilies $\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{A}' \subseteq \mathfrak{B}$ there is no $d$ separating them. This is a slightly stronger property than just the negation of $D^+(\omega_1, \omega_1)$ for $\mathfrak{B}$. Such a family is called a Luzin gap.

The construction of a Luzin gap $\mathfrak{B}=\langle B_{\alpha}: \alpha <\omega_1 \rangle$ is almost the same as the usual inductive construction of an AD family of size $\aleph_1$, with one modification. At stage $\alpha$ one chooses $B_{\alpha}$ almost disjoint from each of the previous $B_{\beta}$ with the additional property that for every $n \in \omega$, $\{\beta < \alpha: \textrm{max}(B_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta}) < n \}$ is finite (where max$(\emptyset)$ is defined to be $-1$). No care is needed at finite stages, so let $\langle B_n: n < \omega \rangle$ be arbitrary pairwise disjoint infinite subsets of $\omega$. Now suppose we have succeeded in building $\langle B_{\beta}: \beta<\alpha \rangle$. Enumerate this set in order type $\omega$ as $\langle A_n: n <\omega \rangle$. Let $x_n$ be any element in $A_n \setminus A_0 \cup \ldots \cup A_{n-1}$ greater than $n$, and let $B_{\alpha}=\{x_n: n\in\omega\}$. Then $B_{\alpha}$ is almost disjoint from every $B_{\beta}$, $\beta < \alpha$, and furthermore has the desired property.

The AD family $\mathfrak{B}$ is a Luzin gap. To see this, fix two disjoint and uncountable subfamilies $\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{A}' \subseteq \mathfrak{B}$, and suppose toward a contradiction there is a $d \subseteq \omega$ separating them, that is, a $d$ that is almost disjoint from every $B \in \mathfrak{A}$ and that almost contains every $B \in \mathfrak{A}'$. For every $B \in \mathfrak{A}$, let $n_B = \textrm{max}(d \cap B)$. There must be some $m$ such that for uncountably many $B \in \mathfrak{A}$ we have $n_B = m$. Pick some $B_{\alpha} \in \mathfrak{A}'$ of large enough index so that $\{\beta < \alpha: B_{\beta} \in \mathfrak{A} \, \textrm{and} \, n_{B_{\beta}}=m\}$ is infinite. We chose $B_{\alpha}$ so that $\{\beta < \alpha: \textrm{max}(B_{\alpha} \cap B_{\beta}) \leq m \}$ is finite. Since $d$ almost contains $B_{\alpha}$, it must be that $\{\beta < \alpha: \textrm{max}(d \cap B_{\beta}) \leq m \}$ is also finite, an immediate contradiction.

Comment: Ervin  Thank you for the answer and also for introducing the notion of Luzin gap.